# Disabling tkinter ttk scale widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to disable all of the (ttk) widgets in a frame, but it appears that the scale widget is giving me some trouble, as it throws the following exception:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"

Some relevant code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def disable_widgets(parent):
    for child in parent.winfo_children():
        child.config(state = 'disabled')

root = tk.Tk()

# Frame full of widgets to toggle
frame_of_widgets = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_of_widgets.pack()

# Button to be disabled
button_to_disable = ttk.Button(frame_of_widgets)
button_to_disable.pack()

# Entry to be disabled
entry_to_disable = ttk.Entry(frame_of_widgets)
entry_to_disable.pack()

# Scale to be disabled
scale_to_disable = ttk.Scale(frame_of_widgets)
scale_to_disable.pack()

# Button that disables widgets in frame
disable_button = ttk.Button(root,text="Disable",command= lambda: disable_widgets(frame_of_widgets))
disable_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It works for the button and entry, but not for the scale. I thought one of the benefits of ttk was making widgets more uniform with common methods and attributes, so I am guessing perhaps I am accessing all three of these widgets incorrectly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For ttk widgets you use the `state` method. The `state` method for buttons and entry widgets are just a convenience function to mimic the standard button and entry widgets.

You can rewrite your function like this:

```
def disable_widgets(parent):
    for child in parent.winfo_children():
        child.state(["disabled"])
```

ttk states are mentioned in the ttk documentation here (though the description borders on useless): https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#widget-states

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! 

I had previously tried child.state('disabled'), which also seemed to work for the button and entry but not for the scale. It turns out making it a list did the trick. Also interestingly, it seems 'normal' and 'enabled' don't seem to work either, as I need to use '!disabled'. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

another way:

```py
scale_to_disable.configure(state='disabled')  # 'normal'
```

You can consider that set the breakpoint at the `configure` of the class Scale (`from tkinter.ttk import Scale`) may get some helpful.

The following is part of the code to intercept the `class Scale`

```
class Scale(Widget, tkinter.Scale):

    ...

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kw):
        if cnf:
            kw.update(cnf)
        Widget.configure(self, **kw)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. When posted as an image, it's not searchable, and people can't copy it.

Comment: I have stated that this code is located in the native Python library. (``Python37\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py -> class Scale ...``)

The reason not to write the code in the picture directly is that I think it is important to find the answer in the native code,
So I only provide the location of the source, I hope users can go and see for themselves

And even if I write the code of the picture, it is useless, because I can’t write all the dependent code, and few people are willing to read a long story,
That’s why I encourage the user to look at the native code and hope you understand.

Comment: Images have bad usability - they aren't searchable, and visually impaired people won't be able to get any information at all.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I improved my answer, I realized that the picture could still be expressed in words.